# How to find if String really MATCHES regex

Tags: swift, regex

Is there a way to find out if a string matches certain Regular Expression? So far I have only found functions that are able to determine whether the string contains another string matching the regular expression but I want to find out a way to tell if the string MATCHES the regex.

```
extension String {
    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}
```

this is what I have tried

but when I have regex eg `let regex = HIHOWAREYOU` and i do  `"HIHOWAREYOUUUUUUU".matches(regex)`

it returns true, but i need it to return false

this happens of course if I create a more complex regex such as `[ -~]{1,10}` I specify that the string must have from 1 - 10 characters but when it has 11 the function also returns true

Comment: You probably want to use [Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (i.e., `^` and `$`).

Comment: Or, `\A` and `\z`.